# Limit of $i^\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to \infty$, taking into account the $n$ roots

Tags: limits, roots

$i^\frac{1}{n}$ has n roots. If one is not careful, the limit as $n \to \infty$ is 1.   Simple "proof": $i=e^\frac{\pi i}{2}$ or $i^\frac{1}{n}=e^\frac{\pi i}{2n} \to e^0=1$.

This does not take into account the n roots, since $i=e^{(\pi i)(2k+\frac{1}{2})}$..  Here $\frac{k}{n} $can have any value with $1\le k \le n$ for the n roots.  Therefore given any $0\lt x \le 1$, it is easy to construct a sequence of $\frac{k}{n}\to x$ so any point on the unit circle will be the limit of a sub-sequence.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your question? As you say, there are $n$ roots and you haven't uniquely specified one; in other words, $n \mapsto i^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is not a well-defined sequence at all. You can make it well-defined by explicitly choosing an $n^{th}$ root for every $n$, and the limit (if it exists) depends on that choice. What is confusing here?

Comment: My question:  Does the limit $i^\frac{1}{n}$ exist?  What I am attempting to show that as $n\to \infty$, many sequences can be created with these different limits.

Comment: If you are considering the $n$ roots at each step, then you aren't so much taking the limit of a *sequence of numbers* but rather of a *sequence of sets of numbers*.

Comment: That question does not make sense. The limit is an operation we perform on a sequence. This isn't a well-defined sequence, for exactly the reason you've already explained.

Comment: On the other hand, one could ask a different question: is there a meaningful way to take the limit of the *sets* given by all the $n^{th}$ roots of unity? And the answer is yes, there are various ways to do this. For example one could ask for the limit with respect to the Hausdorff metric (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), and the answer is the entire unit circle $S^1$.

Comment: Well defined sequence (1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3).... with k the first digit and n the second digit.  My assertion is that for any real number (0,1], you  can find a sub-sequence (with increasing second digit) as its limit.

Comment: So what is your *question*?

Comment: I think a more accurate way of stating what you are after in the question (I cannot even comprehend your comment) is that for any point $p$ on the unit circle, there is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that for each $n, a_n^n = i$ and $\lim_n a_n = p$. This is not hard to show, just take $a_n$ to be the closest $n$-th root of $i$ to $p$. There is nothing special about $i$ here. You could equally well do it with the $n$-th roots of any other point on the unit circle.

Comment: My last comment was to define an explicit sequence, where sub-sequences can be used to define points on the unit circle.  Also most sub-sequences won't converge.  The point of my question was a refutation of a claim that$i^\frac{1}{n} \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$